# Differentiate beam vs ray vs streak

Tags: difference

Friends, could you please differentiate the words in context:

- a **beam** of *light*
- a **ray** of *light*
- a **streak** of *light*

Subtle differences, major differences, nuances, practical differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**beam**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/beam) of light is like the output of a car's headlight, a torch (flashlight) or a searchlight, and can be quite wide.

A [**ray**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ray) of light is a thin line, such as the first flash of light at dawn, or in a scientific experiment with prisms, or a mathematical theoretical item (the linear equivalent of a point).

A [**streak**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/streak) of light suggests motion, such as the trace from a shooting star, or a line across a painting.